# How to Create an ES6-module that does not cause errors on older browsers?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module

In my js-file I have the following statement which allows ES6-supporting browsers import the function "cisf" from the file containing it:

```
export function cisf ()
{ return 123;
}
```

However I assume that the above would cause errors on some older browsers. Would it not?

Is there a way to make the ES6 export-statement conditional so that it does not cause errors on older browsers but still allows the loading of the code as an ES6 module by newer browsers?

I'm only interested in making sure I don't cause errors on (relative recent) non-ES6-compliant browsers, not on how older browsers would get access to the same code, because they can get it in the pre-ES6 way.

I'm specifically trying to avoid having to produce and maintain two versions of the file being loaded. It would be a nice extra if such a module could also be loaded on Node.js, without having to create a different version of the file.

EDIT: I specifically would like to know if it can be done without Babel and/or WebPack or similar, in plain Javascript.

Comment: This is what Babel is for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I kinda know it is possible with tools like Babel and and perhaps WebPack, but is there any way to do it in pure JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I assume that the above would cause errors on some older browsers. Would it not?

No, it would not. Older browser do not understand `<script type="module">`, and will not try to execute it. It's just ignored like any script with an unknown type. There won't be an error, it would just do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no way to create a module (or write a code) in ES6/ES7 without transpiling it to ES5 that would work in older browsers.
You HAVE to use babel to compile the code. Don't even waste your time finding a solution for it.

The reason is, older browsers do not understand the new ES6/ES7 syntax, period.

You should ship your final bundled code as ES5 as the best industry practice (at least until all older browsers have no more users)

Comment: Ok I believer you, there's no way to do it. But transpiling is not exactly what I want to do because my code is already ES5-compatible.  I was just wondering  if I there's a way to make it so that it can also be loaded as an ES6 module by those who would want to do that.  You are basically saying we should not ship any ES6 modules until "older browsers have no more users". Yet some customers might prefer that we do ship ES6 modules even though older browsers are still being used, by others.

Comment: @PanuLogic, sorry, but I don't understand the use case here. Why would some customers demand an ES6 module to be shipped to them? Can you elaborate on the business use case?

Comment: Well maybe they have decided to standardize on using only ES6 modules. You may question the wisdom of their decisions and use-cases  but I think the customer is always right.

Comment: I honestly don't think the customer is always right. They can make mistakes for so many reasons, and it is also your job as a consultant to enlighten them and tell them what the correct way of doing things are. At the end they can leave or take your advice.